# Blanked terminal in screen when quitting emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, gnu-screen

I use emacs in terminal mode (i.e., launched with the -nw option) in screen. When I quit or suspend emacs, instead of getting back my terminal with the history of previous command and outputs of these commands, I see a blank terminal with only the current prompt showed (*).

This is not the same thing as what would happen with the option altscreen off, as all content from emacs disappears from the terminal.

Things that seem strange to me:
 - This does not happen when I run emacs outside of screen
 - This does not happen with other full-screen apps such as vim or less
 - This does not happen on other computers with the same .screenrc, .bashrc, etc.

The computer on which the problem occurs runs scientific linux, Screen version 4.00.03 and Emacs 23.1.1.
I have no problem on two computers running debian, Screen version 4.00.03jw4 and Emacs 23.2.1.

What could be the reason for this?

(*) Note that what I see is not equivalent to a terminal that has been cleared, as the prompt does not appear on the first line of the terminal but on the line it should be if the history of previous commands and outputs had not been erased, i.e. I see several blank lines, then the prompt.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour if you launch Emacs with `emacs -Q -nw`?

Comment: Yes, I get the exact same behaviour.

Comment: Could you start logging in screen (C-a H if memory serves) and compare the logging output of entering emacs then exiting in both your setups?  What do you see when you scroll back in screen after exiting emacs?  Does that happens with tmux also?

Comment: @juanleon: I'm not sure how to interpret the files I obtain when logging in screen, as they are full of control characters. Running diff on the two files has a strange effect because of these controls characters I guess (I see the emacs start screen blink on the terminal). Looking at the diffs by hand it seems that most of them are due to different configurations in emacs. The last line is different, it reads  <br/>^[[34h^[[?25h^[[34l^[[63;1H^[[K^[[?1l^[>^[[34h^[[?25h^[[?1049l^[[39;49m^M^[]0;login@computer.fr: /home/login^G$  on the computer where the problem is,

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble with the formatting.
So the last line reads  
^[[34h^[[?25h^[[34l^[[63;1H^[[K^[[?1l^[>^[[34h^[[?25h^[[?1049l^[[39;49m^M^[]0;login@computer.fr: /home/login^G$   

on the computer with the problem  
and  
^[[34h^[[?25h^[[34l^[[63;1H^[[K^[[?1l^[>^[[34h^[[?25h^[[?1049l^[[39;49m^M$     

on the one where things work fine.

Comment: And when I scroll back in screen after exiting emacs I see nothing -- all lines are blank.

Comment: The difference in that line seems to be related to bash prompt... It is a long shot but have you tried if the error happens after doing "PS1=foo"? Another thing worth trying is stty -a > stty-before; emacs ; stty -a > stty-after ; diff stty-before stty after.  If diff is empty, try diff-ing stty setting of the computers where the problem is happening and where is not.  Also, when scrolling back, could you check if lines are empty (as opposed to having characters that have the same foreground and background colors)?

Comment: It's not related to the prompt, I should have mentioned that. At first I thought the control characters were caused by my coloured prompt so I ran  
export PS1="$ "  
on both computers before logging.  
The lines I get when scolling back are indeed empty.  
I'll check the ssty thing when I have some time.

Comment: @juanleon: I compared the stty output before and after launching emacs, within screen and outside of screen, and with the other computers were thinks work fine. Launching and exiting emacs does not change the stty output. The stty output within and outside of screen is the same.  
The only difference between the computer that works and the current one is that the current one has the additional setting '-cdtrdsr'.  
Enabling it (with 'stty cdtrdsr') does not change anything.

Comment: I should also mentioned that I have compared the environment variables inside and outside of screen, and tried mimicing the environment without screen inside of screen, and I could not find anything that had any impact on the observed behaviour.